# Starship cross-shell prompt is not working on Mac zsh

Tags: zsh, command-prompt, zshrc

I'm using a Mac and followed the [instructions](https://starship.rs/guide/#%F0%9F%9A%80-installation) to install with homebrew and added `eval "$(starship init zsh)"` to `~/.zshrc`.
However, when I restarted my terminal it still shows the default one.

Here's the content of my `.zshrc` (added the line at the bottom)

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin

eval "$(starship init zsh)"
```

Comment: I don't see on the page you have linked to, where `eval $(starship ....)` is explained. For debugging, I would first run on the command line a plain `starship init zsh`, to get some idea what it does. I would expect that it writes to stdout several commands for setting up the prompt, and you can then investigate them, whether they look reasonable.

Comment: I now found on the installation instruction about the `eval` line, so this is likely correct. Still, I would do a manual _starship init zsh_; otherwise I don't see how a reasonable debugging could be done. Also, did you fulfill the prerequisite mentioned on the weg page (i.e. installing the font)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've currently the same problem. But Starship is initializing when i launch zsh manually. Are you by any chance using an Apple Silicon? I've the same on an M2, but it works perfectly on a Intel machine with the same dotFiles.

Comment: I got the exact same problem. My dot files are working on a Mac with Intel. Copied them to a M2 Mac via Airdrop and it only works when doing an exec zsh. This is pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

is your zsh configured with the "recommended" defaults? there are 3 lines(i forget the exact lines, i've already deleted them) in the start that initializes its own prompt. deleting that, closing and launching the terminal again fixed the problem for me (on PopOS, which is linux, but macos is close enough so it should work)